# Trigger JQuery animate scrollTop after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function that animate which works fine when I trigger it from a button click, but when I'm trying to trigger it when I'm scrolling the div the animation is on the animation get jumpy (jump to the top of the div).

EDIT: A jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/mxubjhko/5/

Here is the eventListener code:

```
var lastPosition = 0;
var doneAnimate = true;
var lastID = 1;
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current = document.getElementById("content").scrollTop;
    if (lastTopPosition > current) {
      if (doneAnimate) {
        Slide(lastID - 1);
      }
    } else if (lastTopPosition < current) {
      if (doneAnimate) {
        Slide(lastID + 1);
      }
    }
    lastTopPosition = current;
    return false;
  })
}
```

And here is the animation function:

```
function Slide(ID) {
  console.log(ID)
  lastID = ID;
  $("#content").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#part" + ID).offset().top
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "linear",
      complete: function() {
        doneAnimate = true;
      },
      start: function() {
        doneAnimate = false;
      }
    }


  );
}
```

Comment: Use a debouncer -> https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Can you provide a working preview of what the problem is?

Comment: @Adam just added. Notice that when triggered by the let have a look button it works perfectly